# Samsung Galaxy J1 bootloop after flashing SuperSU

Tags: samsung, rooting, boot-loop

I can't turn on my Samsung Galaxy J1 (SM-J120G) running on Android 5.1.1 Lollipop after I did the following actions. I flashed TWRP using Odin, then flashed `supersu.zip` with TWRP (latest version of SuperSU), then I rebooted and stuck with the SAMSUNG logo.

I removed the battery, again inserted, and went to the TWRP custom recovery, then I did a normal reset without changing any settings. The phone shows the boot screen and Samsung animation, but after that, the phone boots again from start. This process repeats infinitely.

Please help me fix that.

Comment: Download UPDATE-unSU-signed.zip, flash it in TWRP, wipe cache & dalvik, then restart the phone. Flash magisk if you SuperSu is not working for you.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't joined the site after the question was migrated, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung is notorious for boot loops. You are having problems with the system integrity check that's run by the kernel. You need to install a systemless root. Magisk uses systemless root, however, I prefer SuperSU.

You just need to install the correct systemless root zip. I have a SuperSU installer for Android 5.1.1, [SuperSU v2.82 Systemless](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1tkSE7VAyRZVHlB5FIZkuCvSWsG6BsAOU&export=download). For some strange reason, I was able to enable full root access after installing the systemless zip. To enable the full root like I did, you need TWRP 3.2+:

- Open TWRP and install SuperSU with TWRP (install full root using TWRP)
- Do not reboot yet, install the systemless root zip, it will automatically change to "system root mode" and install root access bypassing the systemless install.
- After literally 10 minutes of boot time, my device boots with full root access.